# How to force Datatables to re-render or re-load static dat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatable that uses static data from an HTML file.

Using either the "columnDefs data" function, or the "columnDefs render" function, I can perform some output adjustment - blanking out some of the TD's based on their content, and their position on the currently displayed page (without altering the data source).

However, when a user changes the number of displayed rows, I then need to reset & redo my adjustments on the data, as different cells will now need blanking, and previously blanked entries may need showing again.

So, what I want to do is in the "length.dt" event (number of display rows just changed), call **something** that causes the Datatable to either re-render the entire table, or re-load the entire data (which would thereby call my columnDefs  render or columnDefs data functions)

Is this possible? Or is my approach flawed and I need to find another way?

Comment: To clarify: you load some data, and modify the output using render. You now want to be able to 'reset' the data to the pre-rendered (ie unmodified) state? Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. Reset when the visible row count changes, so I can then modify the output from scratch.

Comment: Using `render` modifies the data at the point of being rendered, hence it's name.  There are a couple of things you could do - have a condition in `render` which modifies the output in one case, and shows unmodified data in another case.  Alternatively look at 'fnRowCallback' which you can use the modify the data after the row has been rendered.  Again there would have to be a conditional statement to determine what gets displayed. Or use jquery to modify the table after it's been rendered, then `fnDraw()` would reset it to an unmodified state.

Comment: Render, it would seem, only gets called once, when the table is first created. If I later do something, say change the number of rows displayed, render doesn't get called again. That's kinda what I'm looking for. A way to force render to occur again, thereby resetting the data its going to draw, when the number of rows change.

Comment: Are you talking about the `render` at row level ie `'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {`?  This _does_ get called every time the table is drawn -debug it or put an `alert` in to check this.

Comment: I was using `"columnDefs": [ { "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { MY_CODE_HERE }, "targets" : [1] },`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`rows().invalidate()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.invalidate%28%29) to invalidate data for all rows and [`draw()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) to redraw the table.

Please note that `'data'` in `rows().invalidate('data')` is required if you use Javascript data structure (with `data` or `columns.render` options).

```
$('#your_table').DataTable()
   .rows().invalidate('data')
   .draw(false);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm changing values with AJAX and this lines are convenient when data is changing at the server, so it forces re-render getting the last info.

Answer (score 2):

You can redraw the entire DataTable on the length.dt event.

```
$('#your_table').on('length.dt', function (){
     setTimeout(function() {
         //draw('page') redraws your DataTable and preserves the page where it was
         $('#your_table').DataTable().draw('page');
     }, 100);
});
```

**Edit**

Here you can see more info and other parameters to pass to the draw method: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work. 
Draw() uses a set of data that has already modified by my code. (i.e. data with cells already emptied, not the complete source data)
I need to reset that data (i.e. refill the cells I blanked from the original static source data) so that I can perform my adjustment (blanking) again.

Comment: But if it is already redrawing the cells in blank, why do you need to reload the original source data and blank it again if it will be the same result?

Comment: Because whether the cell should be blank or not is based on how many rows are being displayed. So when the user changes the number of displayed rows, I need to start from the original data, then adjust the output accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you need to create the table again from 0 with jQuery or DOM and then convert it to DataTable, but it may not be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'destroy': true`.

```
$("#your_table").dataTable({
  'destroy': true
})
```